# Using class from another project in java

Tags: java, classpath, maven-dependency, eclipse-classpath

I am working on a java project A which is using a class from project B. I added project B in the build path of Project A, I am getting error at compile time for the classes I have used from project B but when I run project A it is showing error ClassNotFound error for the dependencies of project B.

Is there any way I can solve this without adding all the dependencies of project B in build path of project A ?
Both Project A and B are maven project.

Comment: are you using maven?

Comment: Yes both of them are maven project

Comment: Then instead of putting in classpath, you add dependency of project B in project A. That should solve your problem.

Comment: In my understanding, we need to provide the jar while using dependency in maven and I am working simultaneously on both the projects so I cannot actually add project B as dependency directly. Correct me if I am wrong here. Is there any way of adding the project folder as maven dependency?

Comment: There should not be any sort of  cyclic dependency.. means project a can be build after adding dependency from project b, but project b should be build indepndently of project a. When you are doing frequent changes just execute mvn clean install for both of the project... your changes will be reflected